# PowerApps connectors in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, powerapps, power-automate

I'm trying to use Power Apps for Makers and Power Apps for Admins connectors in a Azure Logic App, is there any way to use them on a Logic App like we can use them on Power Automate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to use them in logic app, we can see the document of [Power Apps for Makers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerappsforappmakers/) and [Power Apps for Admins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerappsforadmins/) show us they don't support logic app service.
[image]

If the connector support logic app, its document should show like:
[image]

You can also create a ticket on Azure Feedback [page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps)(for logic app) to suggest develop team to add this feature.